# Importing registered servers from sql mgmt studio 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have just got SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008 installed on my machine. Previously I was working with SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2005. I had stored a number of databases under Registered Servers in 2005. I am able to export these to a .regsrvr file from 2005. But I don't see any option in 2008 to import these.

Can you please advice on how the registered servers can be imported into SQL Mgmt Studio 2008?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the registered servers window (View > Registered Servers) open Database Engine.  Right click on Local Server Groups, then select Tasks then Import.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I can't import the file exported from 2005 to 2008 as the xml formats are very different.

Comment: Do you still have access to the machine which had SQL 2005 on it?  Can you upgrade that machine to SQL 2008? Or are you trying to do all this on one machine.

Comment: One machine. I have several servers registered, so I am just trying to migrate the registrations rather than re-creating all of them in 2008.

Comment: You should be able to right click on "Local Server Groups" select "Tasks" then "Previously Registered Servers" and it should import the information from the old registry keys.

Comment: Yes! Thanks mrdenny :) This has saved a lot of my time :D